# Smooth Page Transitions in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have been looking at various websites, and I am not sure how they can change the URL of a page, without the screen going white before loading and creating the effect of a single-page application.

The best example of this that I have found is Google Maps.

Even when you just move the map, the URL changes. Example:

https://www.google.com.au/maps/@17.130084,29.4713099,3z

https://www.google.com.au/maps/@43.4447851,98.7291224,3z

When you open these from Stack Overflow, or copy the link into the address bar and press enter, it takes about a second to load. But if you just move the map within the page, there is no apparent loading - just like the URL never changed.

Can anyone explain, specifically, how they do this? Also, I would appreciate some help on how they achieve this single-page-application-style transition with canvas in particular.

I have seen related questions on this site, but none have clarified the issue for me.

Comment: This is done with AJAX.
It's a good question.

Comment: I have seen AJAX mentioned around the place, but I don't exactly how it works with changing the actual URL of the page, instead of just fetching data from the server. And thanks :).

Comment: It is an important implementation, it was actually Microsoft who invented this technology.
In order to learn this, you will need to be a bit familiar with server side things and a good grasp of JS or very least jQuery will be needed as well.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)
It has its negatives as well and by now is out/ resp updated.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @damianocelent - just wondering what negatives there are, and what it has been updated by :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will be using the javascript `window.history.pushState()` method to change the value in the address bar without navigating away from the page, refer to this [MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Comment: Thanks so much, @kevmc :).